# gcc unrecognized command-line option '-soname'

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries, raspbian

Raspbian (bullseye)

I'm going through [A guide to understanding Linux software libraries in C](https://opensource.com/article/21/2/linux-software-libraries)

I got as far as creating the dynamic library which is where I've run into an issue.

I have compiled my source code using,

```
gcc primes.c -c -fpic
```

No problems but when I try the next step to create a shared object,

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libshprimes.so -o libshprimes.so.1 primes.o
```

I get the following output,

```
gcc: error: libshprimes.so: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-soname,'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: ***Why*** are you using `sudo`? That's a really terrible idea. Build as a normal user, and if you need it then *install* with `sudo`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if I dont uses `sudo` then I get `Fatal error: can't create primes.o: Permission denied`

Comment: Build in your own users home-directory (or a subdirectory of it). Somewhere where you have the rights to write files.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am

Comment: ahh no I created the directory as root grrrrrrr

Comment: As for your problem, have you rewritten the command into your question, or copy-pasted it as you actually ran it? In your actual command, do you have a space somewhere where it shouldn't be?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thankyou, it was spaces where they weren't supposed to be!